# A function to group values and print the occurrence

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Input for the function

```
[
    {
        “Item”: “Pen”,
        “Action”: “Sell”
    },
    {
        “Item”: “Pen”,
        “Action”: “Sell”
    },
    {
        “Item”: “Pen”,
        “Action”: “Buy”
    },
    {
        “Item”: “Pencil”,
        “Action”: “Sell”
    },
    {
        “Item”: “Pencil”,
        “Action”: “Sell”
    },
    {
        “Item”: “Pencil”,
        “Action”: “Buy”
    },
    {
        “Item”: “Pencil”,
        “Action”: “Buy”
    }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    {   
        “Item”: “Pen”,
        “sellCount”: 2,
        “buyCount: 1
    },
    {
        “Item”: “Pencil”,
        “sellCount”: 2,
        “buyCount: 2
    }
]
```

I tried to use rxjs operators like reduce and filter.

Comment: Is the input an observable or something? Or is it just an array you need to operate on?

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of this? I don't think you need a external lib.

Edit: Could obviously be cleaner and not use any types, but wanted to illustrate it quickly.

https://replit.com/@TJHiggins1/Stack-Overflow-Group-Count#index.ts

```
const input = [
  {
    "Item": "Pen",
    "Action": "Sell"
  },
  {
    "Item": "Pen",
    "Action": "Sell"
  },
  {
    "Item": "Pen",
    "Action": "Buy"
  },
  {
    "Item": "Pencil",
    "Action": "Sell"
  },
  {
    "Item": "Pencil",
    "Action": "Sell"
  },
  {
    "Item": "Pencil",
    "Action": "Buy"
  },
  {
    "Item": "Pencil",
    "Action": "Buy"
  }
];

function groupCount(input: any[], keyLabel: string, valueLabel: string) {
  const map: any = {};
  for (const i of input) {
    const key = i[keyLabel];
    if (!map[key]) {
      map[key] = { item: key }
    }
    const countKey = `${i[valueLabel].toLowerCase()}Count`;
    if (!map[key][countKey]) {
      map[key][countKey] = 0;
    }
    map[key][countKey]++;
  }
  return Object.values(map);
}

console.log(groupCount(input, 'Item', 'Action'))
```